# create custom module for image uploader

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, image-upload

I want to create custom module for "Image Uploader" , and create grid, in this grid , I want to put `"Image Title","Image Path", "Image", "Status"`, "Dropdown (for the selecting image)". once image is uploaded then admin select image from the dropdown for display image on the frontend.

Comment: so you want we write code for you? you must add what you tried so far?

Comment: no not write whole code. i am created the module , but i want to show images on the frontend page("product detail page"),  which image status is enable.

Comment: did you create the model for that?

Comment: yes i am created a model .

Comment: i added the sample code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is sample code get data

```
 $collections = Mage::getModel('moudlename/modelname')->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));

  foreach($collections as $collection) { ?>
         <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'pathtoimage/'.$collection->getImage(); ?>" >
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it gives the follwing error

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in

Comment: did you change these are you model `('moudlename/modelname')`?

Comment: can you help me out of this problem

Comment: yes chage the .

Comment: class Upload_Image_Model_Upload extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract           this is the model class and i wrote the "Upload" as model name is right?

Comment: add your config.xml only the model part and also did you create `Upload/Image/Model/Upload/Mysql$ or Resource/Upload/Collection.php`

Comment: yes i am created Resource/Upload/Collection.php file.

Comment: `Mage::getModel('image/upload')->getCollection()` try this

Comment: yes i am tried that also biut it gives the same eroor

Comment: can you add your config.xml in question?

Comment: <models>
            <upload_image>
                <class>Upload_Image_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>upload_image_resource</resourceModel>
            </upload_image>
            <upload_image_resource>
                <class>Upload_Image_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <upload>
                        <table>upload_image_upload</table>
                    </upload>
                    <upload_store>
                        <table>upload_image_upload_store</table>

Comment: this is my comfig.xml file for the model

Comment: try this 
`Mage::getModel('upload_image/upload')->getCollection()`

Comment: now not give the error but also not display image. "'pathtoimage/'$collection->getImage(); ?" can you tell me that what i am write instead of "pathtoimage".

Comment: the folder name where you are uploading the image

Comment: i wrote the folder name and also wrote whole path but does not get the image.

Comment: update this line `<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'pathtoimage/'.$collection->getImage(); ?>" >`

Comment: already i am updated. now can you tell me what am i update at this line>

Comment: @Harshil there was error in this line so update this code add your image path folder

Comment: yes i am already add image path folder. but since not getting image

Comment: what is database column name for image?

Comment: "image" is the column name for in the database

Comment: can you  `print_r($collection->getData());` and paste the output?

Comment: there is not giving any output

Comment: from magento...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44719/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-harshil).